# move_uploaded_file php error

Tags: php, upload

Hello I am trying to upload a file a user selects on their local computer to my server through a form but I get the following php error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(bqformtest/uploaded_files/test.doc)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/drawapl1/public_html/bqformtest/index.php on line
>   40
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/tmp/phphhS4QD' to 'bqformtest/uploaded_files/test.doc' in
>   /home/drawapl1/public_html/bqformtest/index.php on line 40

This is my php code:

```
            $target = "bqformtest/uploaded_files/"; 
        $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']) ; 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
        {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
        } 
        else {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        }
```

This is my form code:

```
<form method='post' action='' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" name="upload" size="50" />
<input id="submitButton" type='submit' name='Submit' value='' />
</form>
```

The uploaded_files folders permissions is set to 755. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the owner of the uploaded_files dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide full path to file, or right relative path

```
$target = "{fullPath}/fileName";
```

the path to file is wrong

Comment: If I change the path in this line of code to `$target = "home/drawapl1/www/bqformtest/uploaded_files/";` I get the same error message. I think thats the full path.

Comment: @Ben Paton: the full path must start with `/`

Comment: Thanks was just missing that begining / :)

Comment: @Ben Paton: one other thing - your script is vulnerable to attacks. see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell based on the error message, your script is in `ROOT/bqformtest`. Then you are setting `$target` to relative path: `bqformtest/uploaded_files`. This means the script will try to move the uploaded file from the temp dir to: `ROOT/bqformtest` + `bqformtest/uploaded_files` resulting in:`ROOT/bqformtest/bqformtest/uploaded_files`. Set `$target` to:

```
$target = "uploaded_files/";
```

or

```
$target = "/home/drawapl1/public_html/bqformtest/uploaded_files/";
```

and it should work.

By the way, you are using the name of the uploaded file without sanitizing it which is a major security risk. Don't trust anything sent by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Also Check disk quota for the user. I had this problem and and after many hours of testing I found it was simple. The user's quota was exceeded